# C# Want to remove elements from IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> based on condition using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> ListOfDic = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>()
        {
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 1"}, {"Id", 111}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Pass"}, {"Id", 111}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 2"}, {"Id", 222}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Pass"}, {"Id", 222}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 3"}, {"Id", 333}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Pass"}, {"Id", 333}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 4"}, {"Id", 444}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Fail"}, {"Id", 444}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 5"}, {"Id", 555}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Pass"}, {"Id", 555}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 6"}, {"Id", 666}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Fail"}, {"Id", 666}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 7"}, {"Id", 777}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Fail"}, {"Id", 777}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 8"}, {"Id", 888}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Fail"}, {"Id", 888}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Name", "Stud 9"}, {"Id", 999}},
            new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Result", "Pass"}, {"Id", 999}}

        };

        List<int> StudentsToRemove = new List<int>() {555, 777, 888};
```

I want to remove all elements from dictionary whose id's are 555, 777, 888. **I have tried the below solution but it's not working**, In my project, there are more than 7000 elements in `ListOfDic`. so I thought it was better to convert it to `ToList()` so that `RemoveAll()` would be available to remove elements in one shot. Let me know if any other better solution is possible.

```
//Tried Solution, Not Working !! :(
foreach (var stud in StudentsToRemove)
{
     ListOfDic.ToList().RemoveAll(a => a.ContainsValue(stud));
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to have a student class and store name,result and Id as its properties and create a collection of the. Write a linq to select from the list which matches the criteria. It would be more clear and maintainable code.

Comment: In your above code you have multiple anonymous Dictionary (unnamed) with two entries in each placed within a List. Trying to remove the entry with the ID of those int, will still leave the other entry with the Name stud. I suggested an answer to help you understand the better use of Dictionary as its a collection just like List is and actually powerful if you know how to use it. The key of a dictionary can be of any TYPE (string/int), and the value can be anything like a list, array, your own custom class. So you would just create the dictionary in the proper way you can iterate through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say `ToList` isn't working, but it probably *is*; its just that `ToList` creates a new collection, and `RemoveAll` won't affect your original collection. Even worse, you are creating this list *on every iteration of your loop*.

So to fix your problem, you can store off the new list (and allow the old one to garbage collect):

```
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> correctList = ListOfDic.ToList();
    foreach (var stud in StudentsToRemove)
    {
        correctList.RemoveAll(a => a.ContainsValue(stud));
    }
```

Using `correctList` in place of `ListOfDict` from then on in your method.

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this:

```
ListOfDic = ListOfDic.Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Key == "Id" && 
                                            !StudentsToRemove.Contains((int)y.Value))).ToList();
```

Instead for removing items you can assign a filtered collection to the actual object using the above code. which will check any items in the dictionary having `key` as `Id` and which are not contains in `StudentsToRemove`

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer to your question, but my solution below is to help you understand your coding and using best practices.
The Dictionary class is a collection unto itself and therefore sticking dictionary singletons into a list is bad coding. I would suggest making a class of `<Student>` that has at least the two properties Name and Result. Then using dictionary`<int,Student>` you can make a single entry for each person.

```
class Student
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Result {get; set;}

    public Person(string name, string result)
    {
        this.Name =name;
        this.Result = result;
    }
}

Dictionary<int,Student> students = new Dictionary<int,Student>() {};
students[111] = new Student(){ "Stud 1", "Pass"};
students[222] = new Student(){ "Stud 2", "Pass"};
students[333] = new Student(){ "Stud 3", "Pass"};
students[444] = new Student(){ "Stud 4", "Fail"};
students[555] = new Student(){ "Stud 5", "Pass"};
students[666] = new Student(){ "Stud 6", "Fail"};
students[777] = new Student(){ "Stud 7", "Fail"};
students[888] = new Student(){ "Stud 8", "Fail"};
students[999] = new Student(){ "Stud 9", "Pass"};
```

Then you can remove all the students you want from the list of StudentsToRemove. An example of making a dynamic (at runtime) list to remove all the failing students:

```
foreach(int x in students.Where(x => x.Value.Result == "Fail").Select(x => x.Key).ToList() )
{
     students.Remove(x);
}
```

Just to test your output, to see you have what you want you can use this:

```
foreach(var x in students)
{
    Console.WriteLine("key:{0} Student name:{1} result:{2}",x.Key, x.Value.Name, x.Value.Result); 
}
```

Comment: Mudassir, I wonder if you had an opportunity to understand my solution in how to better use of Dictionary, especially not putting a Dictionary in a List? Just a pointer, you can always upvote other answers or comments that provide useful information to you, as well as other people's questions that you found that are similar to a question that you have at that time